# Phonegap make Post Call to rest service on rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, cordova, cross-domain

I have a rails3 rest service and I am developing a phonegap app in which I can only use HTML5 and Jquery javascript.

I am not able to make a POST rest call with ajax jquery to my rail3 rest service because of the cross domain security.

How can I resolve it. If you can point me to the code for both client and server side I will really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is running from the file:// protocol then you can do a cross domain request. From the [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html):

> Your ability to access cross-domain pages from within a Phone Gap
>   jQuery Mobile application is controlled by two key things:
>   $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages, and can also be
>   influenced by the white list feature in later builds of PhoneGap.

As well make sure you [whitelist the server you](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) are attempting to make the AJAX call to.